# how to show that $f'(x)=x/g(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Given that $$g(x)=1+\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
and that $$f(x)=\frac x{g(x)}$$
show that $$f'(x)=g(x)$$
Can you please provide some hints before giving out the full answer, thank you.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha doesn't seem to think this is true. Are your sure there isn't a typo somewhere? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28d%2Fdx+x%2F%281%2Bx%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29%29%29++-+%281+%2B+x%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2+%2B+1%29%29

Comment: @Adriano I am sure that i inputted the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using plain and simple differentiation? It's important to use chain rule and quotient rule here.

Comment: I have, and it got me nowhere.